# Flash notice on image upload in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-fileupload-rails

I am using the jQuery File Upload gem to upload files.

I want to show a flash notice on file upload, but when I upload an image nothing happens.

I am doing this through Ajax. All other actions like restore, delete and archive are working.
Below is my controller action:

```
def upload
    set_access_control_headers
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
    if params[:picture][:file]
      @picture.update_attributes({
          file: params[:picture][:file],
      })
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Picture is uploaded sucessfully!"
    @frame = @picture.frame
    @pictures = @frame.pictures.non_archived_pictures.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 12)
    @frame.notify_add(@picture.file_url, @picture.message)
    render json: {files: @frame.pictures.collect{|pic| pic.to_jq_upload}}
  end
```

Here is the upload.js.erb file:

```
$("#non_archived_pictures").replaceWith('<div id=non_archived_pictures><%= j render :partial=>"frames/current_pictures" %></div>');
$(".page-wrapper').after('<%= j render :partial=>"frames/picture_modal",:locals=>{:picture=>@picture} %>")
$(".custom-header").after("<div class='alert alert-success' role=alert><%= flash[:notice] %></div>")
$(".alert-success").remove()
```

Comment: `upload.js.erb` is never rendered as you call explicit render in the controller. You can only send one response, json or js. Also - do not use flash here - flash is stored in the session and will show up on the next request.

Comment: You can use `flash.now[:notice]` please see the update in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an Ajax request, `flash`  is not automatically available to the client in the current request. You can pass the notice as part of the JSON object you are returning.

```
 render json: {files: @frame.pictures.collect{|pic| pic.to_jq_upload}, notice: "Picture is uploaded sucessfully!"}
```

In your JavaScript file you can access the message using the passed `notice` key.

You also need to render your response as `js` and not `json` if you want your `upload.erb.js` to be rendered

**Update**

The flash provides a way to pass temporary objects between actions. Anything you place in the flash will only be exposed to the very next action and then cleared out. Example:

```
def creat
  flash[:notice] = "Post successfully created"
  redirect_to @post
end
```

In the above example, once a new request is sent to the server through the `redirect_to` call, `flash` becomes available to the view.

**Update 2**

Use `flash.now` to access the flash content in the current request:

```
flash.now[:notice] = "Picture is uploaded sucessfully!"
```

Comment: thanks @Ali. But i still find it on page reload.When i reload page notice appear otherwise not.

Comment: Thats because flash is stored in the session when you set it in the current request, it only becomes available in the next request the browser sends to your server and after that it wipes out